# How to keep my website online if I turn off my PC

Tags: web-hosting

I have recently got my website online by hosting it on my PC. I am wanting to know if I can keep my website online if I turn off my PC. Appreciate any answers

Comment: The only way is to NOT host your website on your PC, use a web hosting service instead.

Comment: If it's on your PC, and your PC is off, then no, of course not.  If you purchase a plan from a hosting service and run your site from there, you won't have that problem.

Comment: If you want something running while your computer is off, run it on another computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hosted solution or a dedicated server at home (a Raspberry Pi can host a website easily), there is no other way to achieve this. Some computer has to answer requests.

Comment: I do in fact have a Raspberry Pi, and I've been trying to host it on that, but difficulties finding a local server to accomplish it. Like an XAMPP type server but for a Raspberry Pi. Or It's a third party hosting company. Appreciate the answer though.

Comment: You should not even consider running your website on an xampp type server. Those solutions are made for development-purposes only and are not meant to be publicly available. Just search the web for free hosting plans - there are many available.

Answer (score 0):

That is implossible. May you host your website on Digital Ocean, is a great service and it is cheap. There is an infity of other services, but i recomend [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Web hosting. There are many free of there that will host your website, even if you are not online